# How does Autoloading work in PHP with Zend or Composer?

Tags: php, zend-framework, composer-php, autoload

I will have small to big projects in PHP. I would like to understand how to set up a very new project and not ever worry about including things. I don't want to use skeletons. I will definitely use the Zend Framework 3+. I want to use either Zend's autoloader or Composer's autoloader. But don't want to mix them up.

So the dream is to have the following code be able to find any class or function in whatever script the client might request:

```
<?php
    $adapter = new Zend_Db_Adapter_Mysqli("", "", "", "");
    // ...
    $str = randomString(); // function from "myUtils.php"
?>
```

So the question is, how do I set up one of the autoloaders correctly? How do they work? Can you make a beginner understand that? I'm using IIS and my local root folder is `C:\inetpub\wwwroot`. As you can guess I have not much experience with web-dev.

Comment: '*So that it is easy enought for beginners to underdstand and learn.*' - What is this supposed to mean? Are you expecting beginners to look at your code an learn?

Comment: Is your question '*how do I set up one of the autoloaders correctly?*' or is it '*How does Autoloading work with PHP?*'?

Comment: If you are using Zend Framework 3+ then why would you consider using Composer's autoloader and not Zend's?

Comment: Your question should not be "how Autoloading works in PHP?", It should be "how to setup Zend loader"

Comment: Zend uses Composer for autoloading. Are you trying to ask "how to autoload" ? ... Start here: https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md

Answer (score 1):

If you use ZF3 you will  never call a class like `new Zend_Db_Adapter_Mysqli()`, you will use namespaces, like `new \Zend\Db\Adapter\Mysqli()`.

The autoloading of ZF3 is working only by composer by default. So you need to use this for autoloading of your modules. The `Zend\Loader` module is used, if you create own projects, outside of the ZF and want to implement an autoloading on your own. But this is not what you seem to want to do. From the docs:

> While Zend Framework provides autoloading capabilities via its zend-loader component, we recommend using Composer's autoloading capabilities.

You add the namespaces of your modules to the `composer.json` and everything else is handled automatically. To add one of your modules to autoloading of composer, you create a `composer.json` in the root directory of your ZF3 project. Then add a config entry for your modules:

```
"autoload": {
  "psr-4": {
    "YourModuleNamespace\\": "module/PathToMyModule/src/",
    "AnotherModule\\": "module/AnotherModule/src/"
  }
},
```

After changing the `composer.json` you should rebuild the autoloading config by execute the command `composer dump` or `composer dump-autoload`.

More details about modules and autoloading can be found in the [official ZF3 documentation](https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/getting-started/modules/#autoloading).